# how use existing schema to create new tables using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

There are existing tables under a under a given schema, say X

For a new schema (Y) which has the same structure as X, I want to replicate all the tables that belong to the X schema and create then in Y

Comment: what databse, and what db tool (phpadmin, etc) are you using?

Comment: Why don't you just restore schema Y with a backup of schema X?

Comment: Do you want data or just tables? You can simply script out the database and search/replace the schema name in the script.

Comment: I'm using SQL SERVER Management studio

Answer (score 0):

In oracle you can use EXPDP And IMPDP command as below:

A full schema export (metadata and contents) would indeed look like:

```
expdp user/pass schemas=<schemaname> directory=dumpdir \
      dumpfile=<schemaname>.dmp \
      logfile=expdp_<schemaname>.log
```

If you want to import to a different user/schema (the target database can be the same as the source), you can use:

```
impdp user/pass schemas=schema1 directory=dumpdir \
      remap_schema=schema1:schema2 \
      dumpfile=schema1.dmp \
      logfile=impdp_schema2.log
```

In sql Server just follow this link:

http://www.databasedesign-resource.com/import-and-export-in-sql-server.html